# Should mid and instr be used, or indexof and substring?

Tags: vb.net

Some VB string functions have similar methods in System.String, such as `mid` and `substring`, `instr` and `indexof`. Is there a good reason to use one or the other?

Comment: In a VB6 legacy project it might make sense, or if someone was a wizard at VB6 and struggling with NET, it makes some sense.  Otherwise, cut out the middle layer (see Steve's answer) and use the NET functions directly.  - YMMV

Comment: I do agree with all what was said here: by default, better use the .NET versions. One pretty solid reason is that both `mid` and `instr` are 1-based, while everything in VB.NET is 0-based. Including references to methods not following the rules used in any other part of the code might be confusing and drive to problems. For example:  `Dim test0 As Integer = InStr("thisthat", "this")
 Dim test1 As Integer = "thisthat".IndexOf("this")` where `test0` outputs 1 and `test1` 0. Any .NET method/collection, etc. will understand that the first element is located in the 0 position but `test0` outputs 1.

Comment: "might be confusing and drive to problems" == 'a wizard at VB6 and/or struggling with NET'. It **can** be confusing at first, but thats not enough reason to lug the VB namespace around forever.  It also probably prolongs the adjustment period since everything in NET is zero based only, most notably arrays.

Comment: @Plutonix If you have option A and B. In the system AA (following the A-type rules) and someone asks you for a reason to choose one  option over the other one. A pretty valid reason, IMHO, is saying: if you can use A rules all over the place and can choose any of them, why bringing option B and more problems into account unnecessarily? There are more reasons (compatibility with other .NET languages, less tolerant to errors, further functionalities (in 10-15 years lots of things...), etc.) but I do consider that the fact of introducing a different indexing system is a relevant enough reason.

Comment: i wasnt in disagreement!  the whole 1-based indexing is an anachronism to start with and clinging to it just to use a few string operations is likely to prolong any adjustment period.

Comment: @Plutonix OK, OK. For code transition, conversion from VB6, etc. sure that it is a secondary issue. But I think that this was already clear in all what was said so far (including in your first comment): if you want to move from VB6, it might not be so bad to rely on the old functions a bit. My two comments came from the assumption that the code is built in VB.NET from scratch (there are quite a few VB6 programmers, starting in .NET who use the VB6 functions as much as possible, even in from scratch .NET projects). I guess that we misunderstood each other a bit :)

Comment: In some cases, .NET framework versions have better performance. For example VB IIF is a function call. The new .net inline IF ternary operator not only short circuits, but does not require a function call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An example could explain a lot. This is the source code of Mid from Microsoft.VisualBasic

```
public static string Mid(string str, int Start, int Length)
{
    if (Start <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Argument_GTZero1", new string[] { "Start" }));
    }
    if (Length < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Utils.GetResourceString("Argument_GEZero1", new string[] { "Length" }));
    }
    if ((Length == 0) || (str == null))
    {
        return "";
    }
    int length = str.Length;
    if (Start > length)
    {
        return "";
    }
    if ((Start + Length) > length)
    {
        return str.Substring(Start - 1);
    }
    return str.Substring(Start - 1, Length);
}
```

At the end of the day they call Substring....
The story is a little more complex for `Instr` agains `IndexOf` because you could use a compare parameter but also in that case the internal code used in the Microsoft.VisualBasic **COMPATIBILITY** (Bold is mine) library falls again inside the base methods provided by the NET Framework.

Of course, if you need only to maintain an old program ported from the VB6 days, then it is absolutely correct to use these methods. Instead if you plan to continue the evolution of your program or you build a new one I suggest to switch to the NET Framework core methods as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'd love to say you should use `Mid()` or `Instr()` because some of us have been using those functions for years, but I'd recommend against using those throwbacks.  Mostly because the portable target platforms (like for Xbox and Windows Phone) [do not support them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425887/portable-class-library-not-supporting-many-vb-methods).  To me that's a sign that they're going to deprecate sooner than later. I've also read the .Net versions seem to perform better, but can't find any statistics to support that claim right now.

One other interesting note that is somewhat related is that the way in which the `Trim()` function deals with break lines is different. Sample code:

```
Dim strTest As String = ControlChars.NewLine ' OR Environment.NewLine OR vbNewLine
Dim oldLength As Integer = Len(Trim(strTest)) '2
Dim newLength As Integer = strTest.Trim().Length '0
```

So be careful if you're porting code to the .Net versions.

Comment: Hope that you don't mind but I thought that including a code is always better to attract people's attention; although your first point is actually pretty valid. Feel completely free to delete all my edits or change the ones you don't like.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I usually prefer to use the System.String one is that it is more compatible with other languages.  If using c# as well as VB it's much less confusing to stick to the System.String ones.  There are also a number of System.String functions which don't AFAIK have equivalents in Microsoft.VisualBasic, such as EndsWith and it's a bit odd to use a mixture.  The VB ones are for compatibility with VB6 etc which is ancient now.

However - I do sometimes like the fact that the VB versions are more fault tolerant.  The Mid example that Steve posted shows that Mid returns "" in cases which would have thrown an exception with Substring.  There are similar differences with some of the others.  I have found that quite useful in the past; you can end up writing those checks yourself before calling Substring.  It also means that editing code using the old VB style commands to System.String can introduce some unexpected exception.  I work on one project which started in VB5, and I learnt not to replace the old versions VB without a reason quite quickly.

Comment: "Fault tolerant" is not something to be proud of, but right the contrary. A tolerant error system drives to unreliable programs. When you build an application, it shouldn't "tolerate errors" in any case; the algorithm should be built such that it can deal with any situation properly (and thus no error/unaccounted situation happens at all). Substring forces you to build a proper algorithm (otherwise an error might be triggered); Mid promotes some situations to not be accounted for (-> this last comment is completely based on your statement).

Comment: I've noticed the VB Trim() function trims out some characters that the .Net equivalent won't as well.

Comment: @NoAlias ?! Do you mind to support this statement with a sample code? I understand what Stuart says as not triggering an error when you input an index which is bigger than the length of the string, for example. But over-trimming is something puzzling me a bit :)

Comment: Yeah, you're analysis is right in terms of the comment about Stuart's answer, despite me finding myself using the old VB throwbacks more than I should.  For the Trim example I was talking about do Dim strTest As String = ControlChars.NewLine  Msgbox(Len(Trim(strTest))) vs. MsgBox(Len(strTest.Trim()))

Comment: @NoAlias This question is not exactly about any VB6 function; but if you don't mind to write an answer and include a reference to this problem with Trim(), I would +1 it because sounds as something which quite a few people might find useful.

Comment: And it fails also with `vbNewLine` and `Environment.NewLine`!

Comment: Done, also included a tid bit about targeted platform issues with using the old VB methods.

Comment: @varocarbas - I agree generally, but it does rather depend on the "fault".  You use the word "error" later, but rephrased as "tolerant of edge cases" it may be sound a little different.  Certainly in recent years, using System.String, I've at times wanted an empty string to be the result for all other cases, and ended up basically repeating all the checks in the VB version in my own code, which hardly makes the code more readable

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse as explained in some of my comments above, all my ideas here refer to a general case, which is analysed from an objective perspective (i.e., what is objectively better? Option A or B?). Logically, if you are aware about the given situation, whatever makes you more comfortable is what you should use. On the other hand, by relying on the aforementioned objectively-speaking, new user, from-scratch perspective, what you said does not sound the best option to me: if a given method outputs the result from analysing certain inputs, it should trigger an error if the inputs are wrong.

Comment: I understand your position, equivalent to the one in the NoAlias answer (i.e., "I have been using these methods for really long and do feel more comfortable by relying on them"): fair enough statement. But highlighting that some of their "peculiarities" are objectively speaking better is going a bit too far IMO. No big deal in any case: I have just written a comment which I thought that was sharing-worthy.